# Available internal storage

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

My device is showing 1.02 GB of free space in storage settings. But while installing app from play store, it says only 492 MB of space is available.. what should I do, please help..

Comment: Is the app download size 552 MB? So you have 1.02GB free, PlayStore downloads the app and then checks the required size and recognizes that you have only 492 MB left because the downloaded file(s) have already consumed the other MBs.

Comment: No, the app size is about 50-60 mb.. and even if it takes 100 mb of space after installation, why isn't it allowing me to to that..

Comment: valid question. i remember that issue but i simply did not break my head about **why** google play is thinking there is not enough space, i was satified with my own explanation that google play is just coded like garbage and did just find some workaround. but i have read that sometimes the size of cache partition is too small

Comment: Thanks @alecxs, not what should I do, despite factory reset..

Answer (score 1):

Play Store suggests having *500mb of free space* for your phone to work properly. So when have low on storage you can't install large apps even through apks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But this was not the case earlier.. I am using my phone since 2017 and using it with same available space. But from recent few days getting this alert. And I said that I have 1.02 of space available and even if I reserve 500mb of space for proper working, there's another 500 mb of free space.

Answer (score 0):

When you download an app from the Play store, you are getting the .apk file, which is an archive file (like a zip file). If you have a 500mb app, it will require 500mb to download the .apk and then a further 500mb+ to extract and install. There will be a temporary period, during installation where you need a total of 500+500mb, 1,000mb to get the app installed.
After installation is complete, the .apk archive is deleted, and you will again have 500mb free.
Try moving some data off your phone, onto your workstation, so you have plenty of space, then install the app. Once it is installed, and the apk deleted, move the data back from your workstation.

Comment: Dude, I had installed pubg of 1.8gb sized application with 2.4 gb of free internal space.. so this condition of double the size is invalid.